# Create Array of arrays - solidity ^0.8.1

Tags: solidity, arrays

I am trying to push a dynamically created array into a storage array.

inside of a function push arrayTwo into arrayOne like this:

```
function createArray() public returns(bool) {
    
    uint len = arrayOne.length;

    while (len != 1) {
        for (uint i=0; i<len; i+=2) {
            arrayTwo.push(value);
        }
        arrayOne.push(arrayTwo); // getting error in this line
        len = len/2;
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: what is it you want to do?
arrayOne is an array of type uint, but you're trying to push another array as an element rather than a uint. `arrayOne.push(arrayTwo[0]);` could work

Comment: Sorry my bad, did not realize i am trying to push an array into a uint array, is there any way to create an array of arrays in solidity?

Comment: it's a tricky one. have a look around for information on nested arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to declare, access and modify arrays of arrays in Solidity:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Contract {

    uint[5][5] public arrayOfUintsArrays;

    // 8 is the size of the inner arrays and 5 is the size of the main array
    uint256[8][5] public numbers;

    // An example of filling an array of arrays
    function fill() public {
        // While accesing the indices, we used the 8 and 5 reversed, the 5 first and the 8 second.
        numbers[0][0] = 5;
        numbers[1][0] = 5;
        numbers[2][0] = 5;
        numbers[3][0] = 5;
        numbers[4][0] = 5;
        // Remember that in Solidity, the indices of arrays of arrays are reversed.
        // numbers[6][0] = 5; // Out of bounds array access.
        // numbers[4][9] = 5; // Out of bounds array access.
    }

    // Another example of filling an array of arrays
    function fillArray() public {

        // Make a copy of the state variable since it's too expensive to modify the state array multiple times in a loop
        uint[5][5] memory arrayOfUintsArraysCopy = arrayOfUintsArrays;

        for(uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for(uint j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                // Putting any values in this example
                // Remember that in Solidity, the indices of arrays of arrays are reversed.
                arrayOfUintsArraysCopy[j][i] = j + i;
            }
        }

        // Updating the state variable one
        arrayOfUintsArrays = arrayOfUintsArraysCopy;

    }

    function getArrays() public view returns(uint[5][5] memory) {
        return arrayOfUintsArrays;
    }

    function getNumbers() public view returns(uint[8][5] memory) {
        return numbers;
    }

}
```

Check the docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#arrays